# Update existing record and insert only new record of the Datagridview using 2 store procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, datagridview

I want to update existing records and insert only new records of the DataGridView at the same time using 2 store procedures (Insert, Update).

But I don't know how to determine which row is the new inserted row and which row is the existing row.

If the row exists, I want to call the stored procedure *Update*, else I want to  call *Insert*.

These are the two procedures:

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_TBL_PROC_PMS_Insert]
    @INDEXNO nvarchar(50),
    @_PROCESS_INST_NO nvarchar(50),
    @_Order_No nvarchar(50),
    @_GOODS_CD  nvarchar(50),
    @_GOODS_NAME nvarchar(50),
    @_LINE_NO       int,
    @_UNIT nvarchar(50),
    @_QTY int   
AS
    INSERT INTO [TBL_PROC_PMS]([INDEXNO],[_PROCESS_INST_NO],[_Order_No],[_LINE_NO],[_GOODS_CD],[_GOODS_NAME],[_UNIT],[_QTY])
    VALUES(@INDEXNO,@_PROCESS_INST_NO,@_Order_No,@_LINE_NO,@_GOODS_CD,@_GOODS_NAME,@_UNIT,@_QTY)

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_TBL_PROC_PMS_Update]
    @_PROCESS_INST_NO nvarchar(50),
    @_GOODS_CD  nvarchar(50),
    @_GOODS_NAME nvarchar(50),
    @_LINE_NO       int,
    @_UNIT nvarchar(50),
    @_QTY int       
AS
    UPDATE [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PMS] SET _GOODS_CD=@_GOODS_CD,_GOODS_NAME=@_GOODS_NAME,  _UNIT = @_UNIT,_QTY=@_QTY                   
     WHERE _PROCESS_INST_NO=@_PROCESS_INST_NO AND  _LINE_NO = @_LINE_NO
```

And this is button Save click

```
var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("proc_TBL_PROC_PMS_Update", sqlConn);
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

foreach (DataGridViewRow item in grdMaterial.Rows)
{
    if (!item.IsNewRow)
    {
        cmd2.Parameters.Clear();
        int rowindex = item.Index;
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_PROCESS_INST_NO", txtInstNo.Text);

        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_LINE_NO", rowindex);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_GOODS_CD", item.Cells[4].Value);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_GOODS_NAME", item.Cells[5].Value);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_UNIT", item.Cells[6].Value);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_QTY", item.Cells[7].Value);
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont really have time to code up an example for you, but this should help you on your way. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/. This is SQL Merge, it will do a check for based on your conditions and then either do the insert or update for you without having to do the `IF EXISTS` or `IF (SELECT...) > 0 BEGIN..`.. Its a much cleaner execution of things. You can also if you want do a delete in here too, but I tend to stay away from that and do deletes completely separate from a merge

Comment: You want to… _”update existing record and insert only new record of the Datagridview at the same time using 2 store procedures_” … Is there some reason these two “different” things (update existing record and inserting a new one)… need to be done at the same time???? What am I missing?

Comment: I want to know If the row exists, I want to call the stored procedure Update, else I want to call Insert. in C#. I gogole a lot but all are not satisfied my request

Comment: When you state _”I want to know If the row exists_” … begs the question of “what” row exist? “What” row are you looking for to see if it exists? If the grid has 3 rows and you want to know if row 5 exist, then simply check the grids row count? Sounds like you are searching for something.

Comment: update datagridview is no problem, only insert new record of this datagridview is much difficult, because we need only insert the new row , not whole datagridview row

Comment: I will bow to your wisdom, inserting a row into the grid is difficult. I do not understand what you mean by _”because we need only insert the new row , not whole datagridview row”_... what does this mean? A “row” is a “row” in a grid… whole or otherwise.

Comment: @JoHnG . I need your help in code, not language because English is not my native language. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a column with ID of the row (could be hidden - .visible = False), where there will be Nothing/DbNull for newly inserted rows (if visible, set this ID column ReadOnly). Once you insert them into DB, you update the grid and those rows will have an ID. This way you can safely recognize existing and new rows.

Comment: I cannot change table structure because it has may data and in operation, we just using existing table structure

Comment: But you have a LINE_NO, which should *NOT* be entered by user, but should be assigned upon an INSERT anyway. You can use that as your ReadOnly column, the (pseudo) ID column.

Comment: I already use LINE_NO , update is OK but insert is cannot because you must know which is the new instered row

Comment: I don't get what you're asking for. Either you need to distinguish at the DataGridView level, or within an SQL, which you asked in a separate (possibly duplicate) question. In latter case UPDATE ... IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BEGIN INSERT ... END would apply.

Comment: By the way, what is your primary key, if you have no ID? How do you identify your rows, how do you make them unique? This is important to give you right advice.